# Value of the "Last Updated" field on a web page

Tags: user-research, research, trust, case-studies

These days many sites or pages on social media only have a very limited shelf life, in contrast to the standard corporate or organisation website that contains information that have a degree of variability in how long it stays for (e.g. About Us versus News and Events).

There are also websites that by law are required to provide the "Last Updated" information (e.g. government or statutory agencies) while others provide it to show how recent the content is especially if it is not immediately obvious.

I realize that "Last Updated" is very similar to other fields like "Last Modified" or "Last Reviewed", and since they are not all clearly defined I will just limit the question to the general field that is seen at the bottom of the page to refer to the content of the whole page rather than one specific section of the page (which is normally seen at the top, such as for Build Version of applications).

Are there any studies or research to show how important this information is to users for sites that are required to have this information, and how this information adds additional trust for the users when they are normally not required?

Answer (score 2):

The different terms you mentioned as examples mean different things and serve different purposes. Depending on what the content is and what message you are trying to relay to users will answer whether or not such fields serve a purpose.

#### Last Updated or Last Modified

These terms mean the same thing and let users know if something changed since the content was originally published.

Some reasons to include these fields would be to:

- Let users know there is additional content they didn't see before and they should therefore reread everything.
- Inform users that mistakes or misinformation they may have seen has been corrected.
- Tell users any assumptions previously made about the content is no longer valid until the content is reread, since the update may have changed what the assumption was based on.

If there is no reason to bring the changes to the user's attention, like minor typo fixes or updates that aren't important, this field can just be noise. If there is any reason users should know something changed, then this field is useful to let users know they should reread the content or that the publisher no longer supports the older content.

These fields are sometimes also used as a way to let the user know how fresh the content is, but if that is the only purpose, as explained further below, "Last Reviewed" would be more appropriate, since it's possible the content is still up-to-date even if nothing needed to change in a while.

#### Last Reviewed

This field let's the reader know if the content is still up-to-date and reliable. It's basically a way of keeping old content alive.

If something was posted let's say 10 years ago, but has a recent reviewed date, users can assume the content is still valid. On the other hand, if there is no reviewed date, there is no way to know if the content is maintained and is still a reliable source.

Adding such a field will depend on whether or not it makes a difference how up-to-date the content is.

Some examples of questions user may have:

- Can I still trust the information I'm reading?
- Is it okay to cite information from this site?
- Should I expect the solution listed to still work?
- Will this contact information still work?

Adding a reviewed date helps ensure users the content is still valid and therefore trustable.

On the legal side, it also states that the publisher is taking responsibility for anything published to that date.

If the content is something that is not affected by the passage of time, then there is no purpose for this field.

Comment: +1 for clarifying the different fields related to the question - do you find yourself using this much in your designs? Do you think there are better ways to achieve the same experience for the users?

Comment: @MichaelLai Along the lines of what I mentioned above, it really depends on if I think there is a reason to include it in the design. For one site I've worked on, the content was basically used as reference information for research papers. In that case, it was important for users to know which content was up-to-date and which articles were maintained, so I included last modified information since it gave concrete proof of how current the info was.

Comment: On another site I've worked on, there was a blog section that was used as a way to communicate important messages to the users. For that site, I wanted the users to realize when there was new content to read, so I used an updated tag on the navbar and blog post. There it was only important that the user was made aware that the post was updated since they last read it, and the actual modification date wasn't important, so I just used an "Updated" tag instead of writing "Last Modified on xx/xx/xx". Once they opened the updated post, the fact the it was updated became irrelevant, so I removed it.