# Does dynamically updating the date to 'today' on a website affect user experience?

Tags: user-expectation, dates, dynamic-ui, seo

I was quite surprised a few days ago when I visited the latest HTML specs from W3C (they [**moved it to a new website and URL**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/), but it's official) and saw that they had been updated on that very date. I thought, *"Wow, how lucky."* Then I visited the site the next day, and the day after that, and so on. Each day showed a new update date.

I compared the specs from two different days and found absolutely no changes. It seems they are dynamically updating the date. I've seen this tactic in low-quality blogs that aim to cheat Google with *"current"* content, but I've never seen it on a reputable site.

So this got me wondering: Does this affect UX in any way? I think they are misleading users into believing there was an actual update, which wasn't the case. I'm curious if this could impact other areas of UX, such as accessibility.

For reference, **this is the title today October 10th 2023**

[image]

## Edit

Please note the question is generic, I gave this example because it kind of shocked me coming from a well respected resource, but I mean on any site. This is more common in low quality sites, hence why I mentioned an example from an authoritative website once I found it.

Comment: How would it impact the accessibility of the website, specifically to do with how the information is perceived or accessed?

Comment: Just wondering if it fits into Cognitive and Neurological disabilities https://usability.yale.edu/web-accessibility/articles/types-disabilities . I imagine someone with ADHD, OCD or autism may have issues with something that is always new, kind of "Groundhog Day" . But again, just wondering, hence why I ask. As someone diagnosed with both ADHD and OCD, I find it a bit weird, like something is off. Not to the point it paralyzes me or something, it just bothers me

Comment: I'm not sure that I do read whatwg.org as "official". (It does sound like they should be held to the standards of "reputable sites", including honest update timestamps, but I don't think it's official W3C material. Their FAQ says they split from W3C.)

Comment: By the way, a different standard of theirs is not updated to today (at the time of writing its updated date is in September): https://url.spec.whatwg.org/ So it may be that the page you're looking at really is updated in some way. Of course, an update might mean activity in a ticket proposing a change or something rather than a published difference in the standard itself.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I arrived to that page through W3C, maybe they left the link intact for convenience. I'll check on the other comment you made, maybe is a ticket. Either way, the question is generic, I mentioned this specific example because it surprised me coming from a well respected resource

Comment: From my understanding, that date reflects the latest commit date on the repo and it's just so active that it almost always reflects the current date. You can see [the full list of changes by date on GitHub](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commits) as linked from the page (you can see for instance that there were three changes that were made on the 10th of October).

Comment: …actually having done another review, the date is updated every time the build is run as part of [Wattsi](https://github.com/whatwg/wattsi). It just so happens that it runs the build whenever the main branch is updated (using [a GitHub workflow](https://github.com/whatwg/html/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml)).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose if it has affected your experience on the website, I would say that it has for other people as well.

I think one of the problem is that the term used to indicate the 'freshness' of the website is not clear, and it was something that I had asked previously about before on UXSE ([Value of the "Last Updated" field on a web page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/132932/value-of-the-last-updated-field-on-a-web-page)).

I believe that if there was a clear definition of the terms updated, modified and reviewed, then there won't be any ambiguity to the users.

Of course, if the website administrator or owner still chooses to misrepresent the information, there's not much you can do about it.